# Using find to open all files in subdirectories

Tags: find

Could you please help me with find syntax. I'm trying to replicate the effect of this command, which opens all files in each of the specified subdirectories:

```
open mockups/dashboard/* mockups/widget/singleproduct/* mockups/widget/carousel/*
```

I'd like to make it work for any set of subdirectories below mockups.

I can show all subdirectories with:

```
find mockups -type d -print
```

But I'm not sure how to use xargs to add in the "*". Also, I don't want to separately execute open for each file with "-exec open {} \;", because that launches 50 different copies of Preview, when what I need is one instance of Preview with the 50 files loaded into it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `find` I have at hand allows to specify a `+` sign after the `-exec` argument:

From the man page:

```
-exec command {} +
              This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the 
              selected files, but the command line is built by appending each 
              selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of 
              the command will be much less than the number of matched files.  
              The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds 
              its command lines.  Only one instance of `{}' is allowed within 
              the command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.
```

That means that as few instances of open will be executed as possible, e.g.:

```
find mockups -type f -exec open {} +
```